# CommandError: You appear to have guava-jdk5 on your project buildScript or buildSrc classpath

Tags: java, android

Hi i had updated my IDE "Android Studio 3.0" and Build.gradle too but i encountered a problem in **Build Build.gradle (Module APP)**

**Build.gradle (Module APP) after Update it became like this**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abdeljalilkchih.learnarabicforkids"
        minSdkVersion 12
        versionName "\n" +
                "        targetSdkVersion 26\n" +
                "        versionCode 1515.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Message Gradle sync**

```
    Error:(1, 0) You appear to have guava-jdk5 on your project buildScript or buildSrc classpath.
This is likely a transitive dependency of another gradle plugin.Run the buildEnvironment task to find out more.
See https://issuetracker.google.com/38419426#comment8 for a workaround.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi You should update the application level gradle file. By doing this, the issue will come.

```
classpath ('com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.5') {
   exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5' 
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this in ?

Comment: updating to classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5' helps too, I didn't have to exclude anything, just update the plugins

Comment: updating the classpath is the best answer

Comment: Manuela your answer works better no need to exclude anything